# Matrix copying causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I must write a function in C that takes in a matrix (src) and 2 integer values(x,y), then gives out a matrix which contains src x by y times.
For example

```
3 5
2 1
```

with (2,3) is going to be

```
3 5 3 5    
2 1 2 1    
3 5 3 5    
2 1 2 1    
3 5 3 5    
2 1 2 1
```

I am given the structure

```
struct Mat {
  int cols; // number of columns
  int rows; // number of rows
  int** row_ptrs; // pointer to rows (the actual matrix)
} Mat;
```

and wrote this function:

```
#include "exercise_1.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

Mat* matrixRepeat(Mat* src, int num_row_blocks, int num_col_blocks) 
{
  Mat *newMat = malloc(sizeof(Mat));
  newMat->rows = src->rows * num_row_blocks;
  newMat->cols = src->cols * num_col_blocks;

  newMat->row_ptrs = calloc(newMat->rows, sizeof(int*));

  for(int i = 0; i < newMat->cols; i++)
    newMat->row_ptrs[i] = calloc(newMat->cols, sizeof(int));


  for(int i = 0; i < newMat->rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j< newMat->cols; j++)
      newMat->row_ptrs[i][j] = src->row_ptrs[i%src->rows][j%src->cols];

  return newMat;
}
```

Then I am given some test programs: half of them works just fine, the other tough gives me segfault. I know for sure that the tests are correct, so there must be a problem in my program. Can you help me find it?

Comment: "Can you help me find it?". Yes - by advising you to use a debugger. That is the best way to debug such issues.

Comment: This is our second course, and we have not used debuggers thus far. I tried valgrind but it was not very helpful

Comment: Debugger is not usually something they teach. It is a tool you are learning to use yourself. And as sooner you learn it, as easier your life will be in the future

Comment: `i < newMat->cols` --> `i < newMat->rows`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, once again you gave the right answer, but in the comments, bravo! =)

Answer (score 4):

The condition in the loop

```
  for(int i = 0; i < newMat->cols; i++)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
    newMat->row_ptrs[i] = calloc(newMat->cols, sizeof(int));
```

is wrong. There must be

```
  for(int i = 0; i < newMat->rows; i++)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
    newMat->row_ptrs[i] = calloc(newMat->cols, sizeof(int));
```

Note: I think you mean

```
typedef struct Mat {
^^^^^^^
  int cols; // number of columns
  int rows; // number of rows
  int** row_ptrs; // pointer to rows (the actual matrix)
} Mat;
```